# Why would a comment I thought was valid and informative get deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

In regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932055/i-mistakenly-deleted-the-end-of-the-code-but-still-get-an-error) should it survive, I posted a comment to the effect of that they should be "working with a copy" of a file and it was responded to by another member telling  me it was "rude".

I can't for the life of me, understand why it would be considered as being rude. I was actually trying to help them and by not doing what I did before, being the same error.

I found it was valid and informative to let them know that they should work with a copy of a file instead of overwriting their original file. Least, that's what I got from their original title:

> I mistakenly deleted the end of the code but still get an error

This is what I saw from the title I saw before it was edited again.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60932055/2

I then noticed that all of the comments exchanged between the said member and myself were deleted. I find that my original comment being deleted, was wrongly deleted.

Now, as I was typing this up, I noticed that another comment I posted mentioning something to the effect of what I am posting here, was also deleted.

The question was deleted now, so for the moment, this can only be seen by the OP, moderators and 10k+ who have the url for it.

I understand that comments can be temporary but find that my comment about them working with a copy is **super important**. People don't mention that until it's too late.

Comment: The post you've cited has been deleted, and since comments are temporary (this one probably will get deleted as well), there's nothing more to see here.  I'd just let it go.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I won't let it go. The guy who flagged me needs to be advised of this.

Comment: Frankly, they ought to just do away with comments.  The only thing that causes more wasted time is tag merges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Heh, funny you should say that. I thought the same thing about a month ago.

Comment: Have you noticed how most news sites don't allow comments on their pages anymore?  That's for two reasons.  The first is that they don't want to be bothered having to constantly comb comments to remove the trolls.  The second (and probably more important) reason is that they don't want to hear genuine, legitimate criticism about their reporting.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - How exactly do you know your comments were actually flagged?  If you understand commentary is temporary, and accept that comments that are no longer required should be deleted, then your comment should have been deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well Robert, TBH I haven't noticed but I know your words are true and it wouldn't surprise me one bit, and all the better. I agree that comments tend to open cans of worms sometimes and tend to put some people in an uproar for absolutely no reason.

Comment: @SecurityHound Because, they were deleted by someone other than myself.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - If any of the comments to that question were flagged the moderator might have thought it was easier to just delete all of the comments.

Comment: Anyways, to answer your question (in a comment), comments are temporary post-it notes that are subject to removal at any time without notice or explanation.  INB4 comments get wiped here in 5... 4... 3... 2... 1...

Comment: @SecurityHound I agree that the exchanges between the said member and myself after my initial comment to the OP were deleted, ok... but it's the initial comment to the OP that was (also) deleted that I found to be wrongfully done and find that the member in question started an useless fire, if you ask me.

Comment: A fire that is now out, unless we continue to fan the flames here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem here Robert is that how am I know what I can or can't post anymore as legitimate comments? I give a big "DF".

Comment: I don't think anyone knows that.  If your expectation is that anything you post as a comment survives for any length of time, well...

Comment: Just keep posting like you normally would. If a mod thinks you should change, they'll contact you. If you haven't been told otherwise... nothing is wrong.

Comment: To answer the question in your title: because someone else disagreed.

Comment: I understand that comments are temporary but find that my comment about them working with a copy is super important. People don't mention that until it's too late.

Comment: @TylerH Please see my above ^

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It doesn't matter how strongly you feel about your comment being useful; if someone disagrees, they can flag it for deletion. If a moderator agrees with the flagger, they can and will delete it. As KevinB says, just maintain your usual course of behavior. If you think the comment is that valuable that it *needs* to stay, it's better to incorporate it into an answer.

Comment: @TylerH I don't think you're grasping the nature and importance of the comment.

Comment: I don't think you're grasping the nature of comments.

Comment: Even the most important comments are not that important. They are always second-class citizens at best. And a comment can't be more important than the post it was posted under, and that question was not very important at all.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Doesn't matter whether I agree w/ the comment's importance or even whether I understand it. A comment could be *literally* life or death from your POV, but if it starts out with +1 and is only a single short sentence, I can flag it and get it deleted by the system all day long if I want. Likewise, if a moderator thinks it's likely to continue inciting arguments, they're just gonna delete it. As I already said, if you think the comment is so important, **put it in an answer**.

Comment: mountain != molehill

Answer (score 16):

The question was extremely vague. Your comment to it said:

> That's why you should always work with a copy.

Whatever that means exactly… ‍♂️ Quite frankly, in the context of that question that's too vague to really be useful advice, but okay, fine.

Next *some other user* commented:

> @FunkFortyNiner `That's why you should always work with a copy.` is bit rude

At which point it *really* went off the rails as you and that user were going back and forth in some jumbled miscommunication. Since that was all a pretty unimportant sideshow to the actual question, I removed the entire lot of comments. And your follow up comments asking why the comments were removed.

**Comments are for clarifying the question.** Not for chatting, or perhaps maybe useful tips and tricks, or discussions. Anything that doesn't serve to clarify or otherwise enhance the post is free to go. Especially when it escalates.

Comment: There was some vague hinting that OP experienced some problem after deleting code, but again, that was all totes vague. Your comment *may* have been useful. I'm sure OP saw it, so perhaps it helped them. But ultimately it didn't contribute to solving the problem at hand at all, and then it even sparked some "rude" back and forth (even if it was a misunderstanding and not even your fault), at which point it was simply easier for it all to go away.

Comment: *"That's why you should always work with a copy."* - And you removed it? Why? That was an **important** comment for anyone who hasn't been faced with that, or have no experience. Wow.... Ok....  whatever.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I can't see the deleted question, but couldn't you have posted your comment as part of a proper answer?

Comment: @Modus The [question was not fit to keep around](https://imgur.com/a/KITQNj6). Is not the kind of question we want to be answered, but closed.

Comment: @yivi I see,ok.